# Dimension of generic fiber of a morphism between varieties

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, extension-field, schemes, affine-varieties

Let $f: X \to Y$ a dominant morphism of varieties
over a field $k$. My 'varieties' are by definition irreducible
and let denote as $g_X \in X$ and $g_Y \in Y$ their generic points. Dominant
means that $f(g_X)=g_Y$. Let $n= \dim(X), m= \dim(Y)$.
Then it is known that the transcendence degree of function fields
of varieties coinside with their dimensions. Therefore
$\operatorname{trdeg}_k \ K(X) =\dim(X)=n$ and $\operatorname{trdeg}_k \ K(Y) =\dim(Y)$.

I want to check that the dimension of the
generic fiber $X_{g_Y} = f^{-1}(g_Y)$ is
$e= n-m$.

My 'proof' has some gaps I would like to plug. Assume that
both varieties are affine: $X= \operatorname{Spec}(A), Y=\operatorname{Spec}(R)$. The map $f$
is dominant, therefore $R \to A$ is injective.
The affine ring of generic fiber $X_{g_Y}$
is $A \otimes_R K(Y)$.
Since $g_X \in X_{g_Y} $ there exist a map
$A \otimes_R K(Y) \to K(X)= \operatorname{Frac}(A)$ und therefore,
since $K(X)$ is a field, we get the induced inclusion of fields
$K(A \otimes_R K(Y)) \subset K(X)$. $K(A \otimes_R K(Y))$ is the function field of generic fiber $X_{g_Y}$.

Question: what do we know about the field extension
$K(A \otimes_R K(Y)) \subset K(X)$? which transcendence degree
does it have?

My idea is obvious: if I can prove that
$\operatorname{trdeg}_{K(A \otimes_R K(Y)} K(X)= m$ then I can
use additivivity formula for transcendence degrees of field extensions
to show that $\operatorname{trdeg}_k K(A \otimes_R K(Y))=n-m$ because of
$\operatorname{trdeg}_k \ K(X) =n$ and additivity for tower of extensions $k \subset K(A \otimes_R K(Y) \subset K(X)$. But I don't know
how I can figure out that
$\operatorname{trdeg}_{K(A \otimes_R K(Y)} K(X)= m$.

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: I believe those two fields are equal. Maybe you can try an example such as $A^1 \to spec k$ induced by $k \to k[x]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Youngsu pointed out, the fields $K(A\otimes_RK(Y))$ and $K(X)$ are indeed equal. To see this, note that $A\otimes_RK(Y)$ is the localisation of the domain $A$ at its multiplicative subset $R\setminus\{0\}\subseteq A$, and $K(A\otimes_RK(Y))$ is obtained from $A\otimes_RK(Y)$ by localising at the remaining non-zero elements. By transitivity of localisations, this shows that $K(A\otimes_RK(Y))$ can also be written as the localisation of $A$ at all its non-zero elements, which is $K(X)$.

So what goes wrong here? The problem is that the generic fibre $X_{g_Y}$ is usually not a variety over $k$! Suppose, for example, that $X=Y$ and $f\colon X\rightarrow X$ the identity. Then the generic fibre is $\operatorname{Spec} K(X)$, and $K(X)$ is usually not of finite type as a $k$-algebra, unless it is a finite field extension of $k$ (by Hilbert's Nullstellensatz), i.e., unless $X$ is $0$-dimensional.

However, $X_{g_Y}$ is a variety<sup>*</sup> over $K(Y)$ (can you show that?), and it is indeed true that $X_{g_Y}$ is $(n-m)$-dimensional as a $K(Y)$-variety! So instead of $\operatorname{trdeg}_kK(A\otimes_RK(Y))=n-m$, you need to show that $$\operatorname{trdeg}_{K(Y)}K(A\otimes_RK(Y))=n-m\,.$$ Now your idea of using transitivity of transcendence degrees works: We've seen above that $K(A\otimes_RK(Y))=K(X)$, and $\operatorname{trdeg}_{K(Y)}K(X)=\operatorname{trdeg}_kK(X)-\operatorname{trdeg}_kK(Y)=n-m$.

---

<sub>* Usually, $K(Y)$ won't be algebraically closed, but I think you're working with the scheme-theoretic definition of varieties anyway.</sub>

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. on your question why 
$X_{g_Y}$ is variety over $K(Y)$ i think the reason is that
we need just to such that $A\otimes_RK(Y)$ has finite type over $K(Y)$,
but that's clear because $A$ is finitely generated $R$-algebra and
base change preserves this property, that's it?

Comment: About your argument on the observation that $A\otimes_RK(Y)$ 
is the localization of $A$ by certain mult set. Here you 
implicitely use that $A\otimes_R K(Y)$ is a domain (not contains
zero divisors except $0$). Otherwise, if a ring $S$ 
isn't adomain, the function field of $S$ cannot simply constructed by only inverting all elements except zero. How the proceed in that case?

Comment: Why can we here nevertheless assume that $A\otimes_R K(Y)$ (and $A$) are
domains? (recall irreducible not suffice for integral, we need
irreducible + reduced). And can your argument in first 
paragraph be 'extended' to case when $A\otimes_R K(Y)$ and $A$ are
*not* domains?

Comment: If $\operatorname{nil}(A)$ is the nilradical of $A$, we can replace $A$ by $A/\operatorname{nil}(A)$ and similarly $R$ by $R/\operatorname{nil}(R)$. This doesn't change the function fields $K(X)$ and $K(Y)$; or more precisely, $K(A)=K(A/\operatorname{nil}(R))$ and likewise for $R$. Moreover, the fibre $A\otimes_R K(Y)$ gets replaced by $A/\operatorname{nil}(A)\otimes_RK(Y)$, which is again a quotient by a nilpotent ideal. Hence also $K(A\otimes_RK(Y))=K(A/\operatorname{nil}(A)\otimes_RK(Y))$. Thus, everything can be reduced to the situation where $A$ and $R$ are domains.

Comment: So we take $K(A)=K(A/\operatorname{nil}(R))$ as a *definition*, not
a *deduction*, right? (since if we would have an
arbitrary ring
$A$ which possibly may have other zerodivisors 
than $0$ I don't know what otherwise the associated function field $K(A)$ 
of $A$ should be)

Comment: Oops, I made a typo in my previous comment: It should be $K(A)=K(A/\operatorname{nil}(A))$, of course. In general, if $A$ is a ring such that $\operatorname{Spec} A$ is irreducible, then $A$ has a unique minimal prime ideal $\mathfrak q$ (which is then necessarily given by $\mathfrak q=\operatorname{nil}(A)$, since the nilradical is the intersection of all prime ideals), corresponding to the generic point. I would define $K(A)$ as the residue field at $\mathfrak q$. That is, $K(A)=k(\mathfrak q)=A_{\mathfrak q}/\mathfrak q A_{\mathfrak q}$. This coincides with the above.

Comment: and the last little nitpick: you mentioned in your answer that 
in general the generic fiber $X_{g_Y}$ isn't a variety over $k$, but
over $K(Y)$. In my first comment I tried to give an argument:
that this is true that $A\otimes_RK(Y)$ is of finite type over
$K(Y)$ because that's a base change of $R \to A$, which is of
finite type. Is this sufficient to check that  $X_{g_Y}$ is
*variety* over $K(Y)$ or does it require a bit more work?

Comment: Yes, your argument works: Being of finite type is preserved under base change. Your definition of variety requires additionally that $X_{g_y}$ is irreducible. In the case where $R$ and $A$ are domains and $R\rightarrow A$ is injective, this follows since $A\otimes_RK(Y)$ is a domain again. Under the assumption that $f\colon X\rightarrow Y$ is dominant (otherwise $X_{g_Y}$ would be empty), the general case can be reduced to the case of domains, as argued in my first comment.

Comment: by the way the irreducibility of $X_{g_y}$ can be also showed pure topologically: If $Y \subset X$ and $X$ is irreducible then $Y$ is irred iff the closure $\overline{Y}$ is irred. But the generic fiber contains the generic point of $X$ so it's closure is $X$

Comment: and concerning your strategy that the general case reduces to the domain
case: here you use that passing to quotient by $nil(A)$ not
changes the *topology* of $X= Spec(A)$, so it is the same
if we check irred of $X_{g_Y}$ or $(X_{red})_{g_Y}$, that's the 
idea behind your (literally) reduction step?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. I really like your topological argument though.