# When tensor product $A \otimes_R S$ of domains remains a domain (or reduced)

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be be finitely generated commutative $k$-algebras
over a field $k$ and $R \to A, R \to S$ are two
finitely generated commutative $R$-algebras. Assume that
$R, S, A$ are domains (or reduced).

Are there any most general criteria when the tensor product
$A \otimes_R S$ is also a *domain* (or reduced)?

(I know only a couple of special cases like if

$\bullet \ $: $S= \overline{k}$ an algebraically closed field, then
$A, S$ domains (reduced) implies $A \otimes_R S$ domain (reduced)

$\bullet \ $: $R \to A$ is *injective* and $S $ is a localization of $R$ by
any multiplicative system $T \setminus \{0\} \subset R$,
then if $A$ is domain, then also $A \otimes_R S$ since that's
the localization of $A$ by multsys $T \setminus \{0\}$
(due to Florian's argument in [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4075247/dimension-of-generic-fiber-of-a-morphism-between-varieties) question)

These are at all special cases and I would like to know how
far the assumtions on $R, A, S$ can be generalized to still
allow to conclude that
$A \otimes_R S$ remains a *domain* (or reduced).

Comment: Note the important counter example: If $L/K$ is a field extension, then $L\otimes_K L$ is not integral -it has idempotents.

Comment: Then for example every idempotent $a \neq 1,0$ is a conterexample because $(a-1) \cdot a=0$. Yes that's nice and this also not violates the first critierion since if $K= \overline{K}$ then field $L$ is finitely generated as $K$-algebra iff it is finitely generated as $K$-modules by Noether normalization, that is if $L$ is algebraic over $K$, but then $L=K$.

Comment: On the other hand can it be prooved that all rings $R, A, S$ for which $A \otimes_R S$ is domain, satisfy neccessarily the criterion 1 or 2 I listed above? What about criteria on reduceness?

Comment: In finite characteristic, the same example I gave will often result in non reducedness - consider $\mathbb F_p(t)[x]/(x^p-t)$.

Comment: If I remember right, this is more or less the only obstruction to the tensor product failing to be integral. There is a precise statement somewhere in Qing Liu's book "Algebraic geometry and arithmetic curves". Let me know if you can't find it.